# SQL Server 05: Reading values from XML datatype in a query

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, types

I'm trying to get all of the attributes and node values from XML in a SQL query.

I tried doing the following, but I'm missing out few values in the output.
Here is what I tried:

```
DECLARE @Details xml
SET @Details = '<root>
    <SelectedCategory CategoryId="101">
        <ItemID>120</ItemID>
        <ItemID>256</ItemID>
    </SelectedCategory>
    <SelectedCategory CategoryId="125">
        <ItemID>158</ItemID>
        <ItemID>120</ItemID>
    </SelectedCategory>
    <SelectedCategory CategoryId="15">
        <ItemID>5986</ItemID>
        <ItemID>20</ItemID>
        <ItemID>268</ItemID>
    </SelectedCategory>
</root>'
SELECT 
   SelCat.CatDet.value('(@CategoryId)[1]', 'int') as "CategoryID",
   SelCat.CatDet.value('.', 'int') as "ItemID"
FROM @Details.nodes('/root/SelectedCategory') as SelCat(CatDet)
```

This is showing the output as:

```
CategoryID     ItemID
101            120256
125         158120
15           598620268
```

While the desired output could be in any of the following:

```
CategoryID     ItemID
    101        120
    101        256
    125     158
    125        120
    15       5986
    15         20
    15         268
```

OR

```
CategoryID     ItemID
    101        120
    NULL       256
    125     158
    NULL       120
    15       5986
    NULL       20
    NULL       268
```

Anybody know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
DECLARE @Details xml
    SET @Details = '<root>
        <SelectedCategory CategoryId="101">
            <ItemID>120</ItemID>
            <ItemID>256</ItemID>
        </SelectedCategory>
        <SelectedCategory CategoryId="125">
            <ItemID>158</ItemID>
            <ItemID>120</ItemID>
        </SelectedCategory>
        <SelectedCategory CategoryId="15">
            <ItemID>5986</ItemID>
            <ItemID>20</ItemID>
            <ItemID>268</ItemID>
        </SelectedCategory>
    </root>'

    SELECT  T.[CategoryID],
            T2.Loc.query('.').value('.', 'INT') Val
    FROM
        ( 
            SELECT 
               SelCat.CatDet.value('(@CategoryId)[1]', 'int') as CategoryID,
               SelCat.CatDet.query('.') as ItemID
            FROM @Details.nodes('/root/SelectedCategory') as SelCat(CatDet)
         ) T
         CROSS APPLY ItemID.nodes('/SelectedCategory/ItemID') as T2(Loc)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works :) But I'm a newbie in parsing XML :( can you explain how this actually works?